# Java Main method not found

Tags: java, inheritance

I am getting a "Error: Main method not found in class Assign5, please define the main method as:
public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application" message. I dont have any errors on the page and I'm not sure what to do next.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Assign5 {

  private String gamePlayed;
  private HashMap < String, Integer > players;

  public Assign5() {
    gamePlayed = "";
    players = new HashMap < String, Integer > ();
  }
  
  public Assign5(String game) {
    this();
    setGame(game);
  }

  public void addName(String name) {
    players.put(name, 0);
  }

  public String getPlayerName(int playerNumber) {
    int i = 1;
    for (String name: players.keySet()) {
      if (i == playerNumber) {
        return name;
      }
      i++;
    }
    return null;
  }

  public void setGame(String game) {
    gamePlayed = game;
  }

  public String getGame() {
    return gamePlayed;
  }

  public int addScore(String playerName, int points) {
    int currentScore = players.get(playerName);
    currentScore += points;
    players.put(playerName, currentScore);
    return currentScore;
  }

  public int subScore(String playerName, int points) {
    int currentScore = players.get(playerName);
    currentScore -= points;
    players.put(playerName, currentScore);
    return currentScore;
  }

  public void listAllScores() {
    System.out.println("Game: " + gamePlayed);
    for (String name: players.keySet()) {
      System.out.println(name + ": " + players.get(name));
    }
  }

}
//******************* Section 2

 class Baseball extends Assign5 {
  private int fouls;
  private int balls;
  private int strikes;
  private int outs;

  private double inning;

  public Baseball() {
    super(); 
    fouls = 0;
    balls = 0;
    strikes = 0;
    outs = 0;
    inning = 1.0;
  }
  public Baseball(String homeTeam, String visitingTeam) {
    super();
    setGame(homeTeam + " vs " + visitingTeam);
    addName(homeTeam);
    addName(visitingTeam);
    fouls = 0;
    balls = 0;
    strikes = 0;
    outs = 0;
    inning = 1.0;
  }
  public void advOuts() {
    outs++;
    if (outs == 3) {
      fouls = 0;
      balls = 0;
      strikes = 0;
      outs = 0;
      inning += 0.5;
    }
  }
  public int getOuts() {
    return outs;
  }
  public void advStrikes() {
    strikes++;
    if (strikes == 3) {
      advOuts();
    }
  }
  public int getStrikes() {
    return strikes;
  }
  public void advFouls() {
    fouls++;
    if (strikes < 2) {
      strikes++;
    }
  }
  public int getFouls() {
    return fouls;
  }

  public void advBalls() {
    balls++;
    if (balls == 4) {
      fouls = 0;
      balls = 0;
      strikes = 0;
    }
  }

  public int getBalls() {
    return balls;
  }
  
  public double getInning() {
    return inning;
  }
 
 
// Section 3: Testing Base Class
  {
System.out.println("Assessment 10 - Classes and Inheritance\n");
System.out.println("Section 3: Base Class Results After Adding\n");

Assign5 gameOne = new Assign5("Canasta");

gameOne.addName("Larry");
gameOne.addName("Moe");
gameOne.addName("Curly");

System.out.println();

gameOne.addScore("Larry", 20);
gameOne.addScore("Moe", 35);
gameOne.addScore("Curly", 45);
gameOne.listAllScores();

gameOne.subScore("Moe", 15);
gameOne.subScore("Curly", 5);
System.out.println("\nSection 3: Base Class Results After Subtracting\n");
gameOne.listAllScores();

System.out.println("\n\n");

 }
public class BaseballTester {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Section 4: Derived Class Results: Baseball scoring\n");
    Baseball gameTwo = new Baseball("Cubs", "Braves");

    gameTwo.addScore("Cubs", 2);
    gameTwo.advOuts();
    gameTwo.advOuts();
    gameTwo.advOuts();
    gameTwo.addScore("Braves", 3);
    gameTwo.advOuts();
    gameTwo.advStrikes();
    gameTwo.advFouls();
    gameTwo.advFouls();
    gameTwo.advFouls();
    gameTwo.advBalls();
    gameTwo.listAllScores();
   
    
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Current Inning: " + gameTwo.getInning());
    System.out.println("Current Outs: " + gameTwo.getOuts());
    System.out.println("Current Strikes: " + gameTwo.getStrikes());
    System.out.println("Current Fouls: " + gameTwo.getFouls());
    System.out.println("Current Balls: " + gameTwo.getBalls());
  }
}
}
```

I know that I need to add a  "public static void main(String[] args)" but I cant figuare out where to put it. I keep getting more errors, also where should I put the closing bracket?

Comment: You want to run the `BaseballTester` class, not the `Assign5` class.

Comment: So I need to change the public class?

Comment: Well, `BaseballTester` is already public, so I guess you must have it in a different file.  Run _that_ file, not the one with `Assign5`.  You shouldn't need to change anything to do that.

Comment: Keep in mind you can only have one `public` _top-level_ class per source file.

Answer (score 0):

Main method is not able to run from the inner class. Put `BaseballTester` class out from `Baseball` class. It's better to put each class to have its own java file.

```
// Assign5.java
public class Assign5 { ... }

// Baseball.java
public class Baseball extends Assign5 { ... }

// BaseballTester.java
public class BaseballTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out how to get it to run and meet the needs of my assignment., which is on inheritance. I feel like any time I touch it there are just read lines everywhere.